# firebase firestore get object/array from document - js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore database currently looks like this:
[firestore db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKdUV.png)

how can I get the value of, say, DEVICES/ID.
currently my code returns undefined when i try to get the value.

```
var userDeviceRef = db.collection("USERS").doc(data.uid);
userDeviceRef.get().then(function(doc){
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        console.log("document customdata foo: " + doc.data().DEVICES.ID);
    }
}
```

`data.uid` returns a proper value. the value of the document ID.
`doc.data()` returns all the fields and its children in what appears to be string format. however when I add `DEVICES.ID`, it returns undefined. how can i get the nested data as shown in the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your field called `DEVICES` is actually an array.  As far as I can tell, it has at least one element in it.  If you want the value of the ID field of the first element of that array, you'll have to index into that array:

```
doc.data().DEVICES[0].ID
```

Comment: YES! thank you so much. it works. can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: is there a way to get all the nodes/children of the devices array

Comment: It's just like any other JavaScript array.

Comment: Wow you are genius man @DougStevenson!! I was struggling the whole day to extract the values in the array. It worked liked a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: @MuaazKasker thanks for posting such a valuable question in this forum :) :).